# Validate Resource in the POST method

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I need to validate a Resource object with `@NotBlank` annotations in the POST method manually.  Is there any way to validate Resource object using  Jackson/Spring api. Not sure how to do it.

```
public class FileMetadataResource extends BaseResource { 
    @JsonProperty("title")
    @NotBlank(groups = {default.class})
    @Size(max = 60)
    private String title;

    @JsonProperty("description")
    @Size(max = 255)
    @NotBlank
    private String description;  
}
```

My custom `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` populates the `FileMetadataResource`

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "multipart/related")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public FileMetadataResource post(FileMetadataResource fileMetadataResource) {
//How to validate fileMetadataResource using jackson here
```

}

ANy help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you taken a look at http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-validation  Seems to cover what you want.

Comment: Yes, i looked at it. Mine is not a usual case  which doesn't fit into Spring's frame work since multipart/related is not supported by servlet and spring spec. So I need to validate the JSON or resource.